# Angular/PHP - Screen output error (SQL request empty)

Tags: php, angular, typescript

I have a few element values from a table that I want to show in screen. To make that possible, I put a ngIf, in case of that element is present or not. The thing is, the output is the non-present element case, but I don't know why.

I put the different codes below:

-user-detail.php

```
<?php
    include_once("database.php");
    
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    
    if (isset($postdata) && !empty($postdata)) {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, trim($request->id));
        
        //Devuelve un empleado
        $sql = "SELECT id,name,email,hentrada_con,minentrada_con,hsalida_con,minsalida_con FROM empleados WHERE id = " . $id;
        
        if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)) {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
            echo json_encode($row);
        }else{
            http_response_code(404);
        }
    }
```

-user-detail.component.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from "@angular/router";
import { Users } from "../users";
import { ApiService } from "../api.service";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-detail',
  templateUrl: './user-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-detail.component.css'],
  providers: [ApiService]
})
export class UserDetailComponent {

  public user!:Users;
  public confirmado:any;

  constructor(
    private _apiService: ApiService,
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getUser();
  }

  getUser(){
    this._route.params.forEach((params:Params) => {
      let id = params['id'];
      console.log(id);

      this._apiService.getUser(id).subscribe(
        (response:any) => {
          this.user = response;
        },
        (error:any) => {
          this._router.navigate(['users']);
        }
      );
    });
  }

}
```

-user-detail.component.html

```html
<div class="row" *ngIf="user">
    <div class="col-lg-8">
        <h3>{{user.name}}</h3>
        <p>{{user.email}}</p>
        <p *ngIf="(user.minen_con < 10) && (user.minsal_con >=10)"><strong>Horario: {{user.hen_con}}:0{{user.minen_con}}</strong> - <strong>{{user.hsal_con}}:{{user.minsal_con}}</strong></p>  
        <p *ngIf="(user.minen_con >= 10) && (user.minsal_con <10)"><strong>Horario: {{user.hen_con}}:{{user.minen_con}}</strong> - <strong>{{user.hsal_con}}:0{{user.minsal_con}}</strong></p> 
        <p *ngIf="(user.minen_con >= 10) && (user.minsal_con >=10)"><strong>Horario: {{user.hen_con}}:{{user.minen_con}}</strong> - <strong>{{user.hsal_con}}:{{user.minsal_con}}</strong></p> 
        <p *ngIf="(user.minen_con < 10) && (user.minsal_con < 10)"><strong>Horario: {{user.hen_con}}:0{{user.minen_con}}</strong> - <strong>{{user.hsal_con}}:0{{user.minsal_con}}</strong></p> 
    </div>  
</div>

<div *ngIf="!user">
    <p>Cargando empleado...</p>
</div>
```

-A fragment of code corresponding to user-detail in app-routing.module.ts

```js
{ path: 'user/:id', component:UserDetailComponent}
```

-Users.ts

```js
export class Users {
  public id: number;
  public name: string;
  public pwd: string;
  public email: string;
  public hen_con: number;
  public minen_con: number;
  public hsal_con: number;
  public minsal_con: number;

  constructor(
    id: number,
    name: string,
    pwd: string,
    email: string,
    hen_con: number,
    minen_con: number,
    hsal_con: number,
    minsal_con: number
  ) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.pwd = pwd;
    this.email = email;
    this.hen_con = hen_con;
    this.minen_con = minen_con;
    this.hsal_con = hsal_con;
    this.minsal_con = minsal_con;
  }
}
```

-A fragment of code corresponding to user-detail in api.service.ts

```js
getUser(id:any){
  return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + '/user-detail.php/' +id);
}
```

At last, I'd like to add a picture of the console navigator, where you can see a console.log from user-detail.component.ts that reflects that the id value is being received from the database (it's the number 1 in the console) and the GET request result, which is empty. However, because is my first post, I can't post images.

If you need more information, feel free to ask for it.

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:** after a few console.log's, appearently the getUser() method (from api.service.ts and its implementation in user-detail.component.ts) is not receiving any data, so maybe it's a PHP error. But, I don't know how to fix it because that code is copypasted from a template and I just modified the SQL query

**UPDATE 2:** apparently, the problem is in the php code. Specifically, here:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

I was using this method for other requests, but those whose parameters come from a form. So, this doesn't work for this kind of parameter sending.

What kind of method should I use?

Comment: "the output is the non-present element case" - what does that mean? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a PHP problem, an Angular problem, or a TypeScript problem?

Comment: You're right @DarkBee. But maybe it's been a copy-paste error, because in my IDE it's ok

Comment: @NicoHaase what I meant is what appears in screen is <div *ngIf="!user">
    <p>Cargando empleado...</p>
</div>
which is the ngIf option in case the user is not loaded correctly

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried some console.log's and it seems that the problem is in the PHP code, because Angular is not receiving any data. The thing is that I don't know how to fix the code

Comment: "Angular is not receiving any data" - what have you tried to resolve that? Also, be warned that the `SELECT` query you've shown is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use prepared statements at all time to avoid getting hacked

Comment: As I said in the update, I don't know what to do to resolve that, so I don't know what to try (that's the reason I ask for help here). The SELECT query is not problem because is not a real application